# mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia': Permission denied

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

When I use dockerfile to build a rabbitmq image, it runs well with docker and kubernetes. but when I add pvc on it, container shows ' Crash loop back off'.
and the error is :

```
The following plugins have been configured:
  rabbitmq_management
  rabbitmq_management_agent
  rabbitmq_web_dispatch
  Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@rongqiyun-dev-base-qqqqqqqq-0...
The following plugins have been enabled:
  rabbitmq_management
  rabbitmq_management_agent
  rabbitmq_web_dispatch
  set 3 plugins.
  Offline change; changes will take effect at broker restart.
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia': Permission denied
Failed to create directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM hub.gcloud.lab/library/centos:7.4.1708

WORKDIR /root

RUN groupadd rabbitmq
RUN useradd -g rabbitmq rabbitmq
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia  && \
    chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq && \
    chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia


RUN yum install -y epel-release

RUN yum install -y deltarpm gcc glibc-devel make ncurses-devel openssl-devel xmlto perl wget xz lsof dos2unix unixODBC unixODBC-devel wxBase wxGTK SDL wxGTK-gl socat git

RUN yum clean all

RUN wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm

RUN rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm

RUN yum install -y erlang

RUN yum install -y initscripts logrotate

RUN wget https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/download/v3.7.8/rabbitmq-server-3.7.8-1.el6.noarch.rpm

RUN rpm -ivh rabbitmq-server-3.7.8-1.el6.noarch.rpm

ENTRYPOINT rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management && rabbitmq-server

EXPOSE 5672

EXPOSE 15672

CMD ["rabbitmq-server"]
```

And this is my statefulset.

Before I add rabbitmq-persistent-storage, it can start normally.
however when I add it, container can't start

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: rongqiyun-dev-base-qqqqqqqq
  namespace: rongqiyun-dev
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rongqiyun-dev
      ns-baseServiceName: rongqiyun-dev-base-qqqqqqqq
  serviceName: qqqqqqqq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rongqiyun-dev
        ns-baseServiceName: rongqiyun-dev-base-qqqqqqqq
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
          value: "12345"
        image: hub.gcloud.lab/library/rabbitmq:3.7
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: qqqqqqqq
        ports:
        - containerPort: 15672
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 5672
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 800Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
          name: rabbitmq-persistent-storage
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 0
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: rabbitmq-persistent-storage
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
      storageClassName: rook-ceph-block
```

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
chmod 777 /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does that line solve the original problem?